# Get numpy image in php

Tags: python, php, numpy, opencv

I try to use in my web application images from a raspberry pi where all images are inserted in a RabbitMq queque. Image is published after I convert it using this function:

```
def im2json(im):
    imdata = pickle.dumps(im)
    jstr = json.dumps(base64.b64encode(imdata).decode('ascii'))
    return jstr
```

In php I tried this:

```
$imgString = $jsonRes->hits->hits[0]->_source->image;

echo "<img src='data:image/jpeg;base64, " . base64_encode($imgString) . "' />";
```

But it doesn't work, is there something that I miss because of python script?
This is the result:

[image]

Images are stored in Elasticsearech, that's the reason I used hits->hits.

Comment: What is the value of `$imgString`?

Comment: You have base64-encoded something in python and then encoded it again in php, maybe this is a source of this problem?

Comment: @vee  It looks like this: `"gANjbnVtcH..."`

Comment: @SUTerliakov I tried to put like this  `echo "<img src='data:image/jpeg;base64, " . $imgString . "' />";`  or  `echo "<img src='data:image/jpeg;base64, " . base64_decode($imgString) . "' />";`

Comment: Is `im` a numpy image (numeric ndarray)? If so, it shouldn't work with `jpeg`. I'd suggest using `PIL` library to create jpeg (`Image.fromarray`), save to `BytesIO` and then encode it (jpeg is binary format, so you encode these bytes).

Comment: @SUTerliakov yes, it is a numpy image. I will try it

Comment: @SUTerliakov 
` np_array = np.array(im) 
 pil_image = Image.fromarray(np_array)
 byte_io = BytesIO() 
 pil_image.save(byte_io, 'JPEG') 
 imdata = pickle.dumps(byte_io) 
 jstr = json.dumps(base64.b64encode(imdata).decode('ascii')) 
 return jstr `
I tried this, message is published, but I still can get the image in php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It gets longer than I can write in comments, so trying to make an answer:

```py
import base64
import io
import json

import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

def im2json(im):
    to_save = Image.fromarray(np.array(im))
    target = io.BytesIO()
    to_save.save(target, 'JPEG')
    target.seek(0)  # Go to the beginning of stream
    # No pickle is needed
    return json.dumps(base64.b64encode(target.read()).decode('ascii'))
```

And on `php` side

```php
$imgString = $jsonRes->hits->hits[0]->_source->image;

echo "<img src='data:image/jpeg;base64, " . $imgString . "' />";
```

You shouldn't `pickle` `BytesIO` itself, you need just to base64-encode its binary content.

If it doesn't work, try removing `json.dumps`, I'm not sure that quotes are really needed.

Comment: to use `to_save.save(target)` i have to specify a format, i used "JPEG" there and still no image printed in php.

Comment: Yes, format is really required, fixed. Could you paste your b64 [here](https://base64.guru/converter/decode/image/jpg) to check if it works?

Comment: I had to remove `"` in php and it worked, thank you!